# Trying to place irregularly spaced lat/lon data on regularly spaced grid

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, matplotlib-basemap

I have some satellite data I am trying to interpolate onto a 0.25 deg x 0.25 degree grid.

I am trying to use `scipy.intepolate.griddata`, but I am getting unexpected results.

I only need the interpolation to occur within the swath of the satellite. I don't need interpolation across the entire globe.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np  
import scipy as sp 
import matplotlib as mpl  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
from pyhdf.SD import SD, SDC

hdf = SD(files[0], SDC.READ)
lon = hdf.select('Longitude')[:,:]
lat = hdf.select('Latitude')[:,:]
refl = hdf.select('correctZFactor')[:,:,70]/100

m = Basemap()

lonMin = -180
lonMax = 180
latMin = -40
latMax = 40
res = 1
lonGrid = np.arange(lonMin, lonMax, res)
latGrid = np.arange(latMin, latMax, res)
lonGrid,latGrid = np.meshgrid(lonGrid,latGrid)

reflGrid = griddata((lon.ravel(),lat.ravel()),refl.ravel(),(lonGrid,latGrid), method = 'nearest')
```

When I plot the data before gridding, it looks like this:
[image: Before Gridding]

After gridding, it looks like this:
[image: After Gridding]

Here is the HDF file I am using:
http://www.filedropper.com/2a2520150314987057

Obviously the resulting image was not interpolated correctly. What can I do to fix this?

My ultimate goal here is to take thousands of these satellite swaths, each of which pass over a different path across the globe, and combine them into one dataset. The point of gridding to a coarser resolution is to 1. reduce the volume of all of the data and 2. to be able to derive statistics for a specific grid point. Another thing: Ideally, points outside of the swath would be converted to NaNs after gridding

Comment: How can you tell that the resulting image was not interpolated correctly? You're trying to interpolat _from two lines_ to a 2d plane! That's an insane amount of guesswork. If you choose a random point in the result, it gets its value from the nearest existing data point. Can you tell which one that is for a random point in the result? I sure can't! Your result is probably correct, it's what you're doing is wrong.

Comment: I guess I should clarify. I don't nee it interpolated across the entire globe, just along the swath of the satellite. Within those two "lines" there are actually tens of thousands of points.

Comment: If you data is 1d and you're interested in interpolated values along that line, use 1d interpolation. For instance, interpolate `refl` and `lat` as a function of `lon`, then your points are `lon_grid,lat_interpolated[lon_grid]` and the data values are `rel_interpolated[lon_grid]`. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: OK, I can see now that your data is 2d, but it's defined along a narrow path of the satelite. So instead I'd ask you to consider what you're going to do with your data. You want to interpolate on a regular grid of 0.25 degree resolution, but your raw data is defined on a strip only a few degrees wide in latitude. This regular grid along a narrow strip just doesn't seem to make sense to me. If anything, I'd interpolate on a grid inside your strip, i.e. for each longitude take a regular grid along latitude, and use that. Really, what you should do depends on what your goal is.

Comment: Side note: your data shows _huge_ variation on a very small scale. I have doubts whether interpolating it will give you additional information, it's more likely that you'll end up with artifacts. So perhaps you should do some filtering or other steps before trying to interpolate your data. Again, it all boils down to your application (and this is tangential to your question as far as Stack Overflow is concerned).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution using a KD-tree/nearest-neighbor look up

```
from scipy import spatial

kdtree = spatial.cKDTree(zip(lon.ravel(),lat.ravel()))
kdtree_gridPts = spatial.cKDTree(zip(lonGrid.ravel(),latGrid.ravel()))
closePts = kdtree_gridPts.query_ball_tree(kdtree, res/2)

reflGrid = ones_like(lonGrid)*nan
for ind,p in  enumerate(closePts):
    if len(p) > 0:
        reflGrid.ravel()[ind] = mean(refl.ravel()[p])

reflGrid = ma.masked_where(isnan(reflGrid), reflGrid)
```

Basically it is taking the average of all points within a 0.125 (res/2) circle centered at each grid box. At least, this is what I think it's doing...

I also narrowed my domain to just the area I am interested in. It runs very quickly.

Before down-gridding:
[image: Before Gridded]

After gridding:
[image: After Gridding]

The horizontal line across the top of the pre-gridded picture is actually appears just be an artifact of pcolormesh

Comment: The horizontal line is probably due to the fact that your longitude data jumps from 180 degrees to -180 degrees; that's why I shifted your negative lon values by 360 degrees before plotting.

Answer (score 2):

As I also noted in a comment, the problem is that you have your data along a very narrow strip, making your data pseudo-1d. If you try to "interpolate" from this to the whole globe, you're actually doing extrapolation based on virtually non-existent values, which explains the noise in your original plot.

Since you clarified in an edit that you're only interested in interpolating in the region of your data, I see a different kind of problem. A fixed regular grid along this narrow strip of longitude-latitude points just doesn't make sense to me. Look at a `pcolormesh` plot of your original data:

```
import numpy as np
from pyhdf.SD import SD,SDC
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.interpolate as interp

hdffile = 'your_file_name.hdf'

hdf = SD(hdffile, SDC.READ)
lon = hdf.select('Longitude')[:,:]
lat = hdf.select('Latitude')[:,:]
refl = hdf.select('correctZFactor')[:,:,70]/100

lon[lon<0] += 360 # shift longitude to contiguous block

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pcolormesh(lon,lat,refl,cmap='viridis')
```

[image: original data]

Hopefully the above plot conveys what I mean: trying to put this domain over a regular mesh won't be useful for any reasonable uses I can think of. Especially if you consider that the few degrees width in latitude for a given longitude is really close to your expected resolution of 0.25 degrees.

So what I suggest instead is to take a regular grid in longitude, and for each longitude take a regular grid in latitude in the domain. This will imply that your final grid is not regular, but it will be topologically 2d-plaid (as if generated by meshgrid), so it will be useful for plotting or other postprocessing purposes.

In order to do this, I'd first construct two interpolators for minimal and maximal latitude values for each longitude, then generate the (lon,lat) interpolating grid, then do the interpolation:

```
# these will be overwritten later
lat_from = lat[:,0]
lat_to = lat[:,-1]
lon_from = lon[:,0]
lon_to = lon[:,-1]

# create interpolators for starting and ending latitude vs longitude
# only use a subset of the 9k data points
step = 10
latminfun = interp.interp1d(lon_from[::step],lat_from[::step],fill_value='extrapolate')
latmaxfun = interp.interp1d(lon_to[::step],lat_to[::step],fill_value='extrapolate')

# create interpolating mesh: regular in longitude, locally regular in latitude
nlon = 360 # ~1 degree along longitude
nlat = 10 # 10 points along latitude for each longitude
lon_grid = np.linspace(lon.min(),lon.max(),nlon)[:,None]  # shape (nlon,1)
lat_from = latminfun(lon_grid) # lower side of the latitude grid
lat_to = latmaxfun(lon_grid)   # upper side of the latitude grid
x = np.linspace(0,1,nlat) # to perform linear interpolation in lat with
lat_grid = x*lat_to + (1-x)*lat_from # shape (nlon,nlat)

# now (lon_grid,lat_grid) broadcast together to a grid of shape (nlon,nlat)
refl_grid = interp.griddata((lon.ravel(),lat.ravel()),refl.ravel(),(lon_grid,lat_grid),method='nearest')
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pcolormesh(np.broadcast_to(lon_grid,lat_grid.shape),lat_grid,refl_grid,cmap='viridis')
# of course we could've overwritten lon_grid with the broadcast version
```

The final plot is visually barely distinguishable from your raw data:

[image: final plot]

but it contains the nearest-neighbour-interpolated values over this rectilinear longitude-latitude grid. I would expect this to be the most reasonable way to interpolate your data, without knowing any details about your plans down the line with the result.

Comment: Thank you. My ultimate goal here is to take thousands of these satellite swaths, each of which pass over a different path across the globe, and combine them into one dataset. The point of gridding to a coarser resolution is to 1. reduce the volume of all of the data and 2. to be able to derive statistics for a specific grid point.

Another thing: Ideally, points outside of the swath would be converted to NaNs after gridding.

Comment: @user3826115 if it weren't for the NaN part, I would suggest that you decimate your dataset instead of interpolating, like replace every nth data point with an average of neighbouring values. I'm not sure how that could be done consistently. And the NaN masking bit could be tricky.